# General purpose BST library in Haskell

Tags: haskell

what is a good general purpose binary search tree library in haskell? We have Data.List for lists, Data.Set for sets and Data.Map for maps, what is the equivalent for search trees.

Thanks, Chris

Comment: What operation do you want that `Data.Map`/`Data.Set` does not offer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Data.Map` is implemented as a balanced binary search tree.

Comment: O.k, but if i use a map i have to needlessly create a lot of value values. I want to store only keys. How can i do this?

Comment: `Data.Set` is effectively a `Data.Map` with only keys.